# Quill Editor: Quill editor removes inline style of margin-left

Tags: quill

I have a contenteditable div that allows the users to tab over. the tab adds a margin-left inline style to the p tag like so

```
<p class="line" id="line-5" style="margin-left: 40px;">Text Here</p>
```

I allow the user to click a modal which open up the text inside a Quill editor. But the quill editor seems to remove the margin-left inline style so the tabs are not shown.

How can I get tabs to work in my contenteditable div so it translates over to quill editor?

Comment: Are you trying to get the editor to show the margin because of some UI you want to add, or do you want an actual tab character \t to be inserted?

Comment: I want a tab character that shows up both in contenteditable divs and in the quill editor. Any recommendations?

Comment: Well I realized instead of adding margin-left to the line for tabbing, I could just insert a tab character when the tab key is pressed. The quill editor seems to pick up the tab character.